# How to resolve 'Conflicting Update' error in Marklogic

Tags: xml, transactions, xquery, marklogic

I am using a function where I have to update (content of the XML) a document as well as its property using `xdmp:node-replace()` or using `mem:node-replace()`. I am getting an error `conflict update error`.
I have also tried using `xdmp:spawn-function()`, but the query does not get executed (i.e no change even after using node-replace).

Can anyone help me with how to use `spawn-function()` or related functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a known bug in MarkLogic 8.0 which prevented using `xdmp:node-insert` together with properties updates in the same transaction. The work-around was using separate transactions, or `xdmp:document-insert` (leveraging `mem:node-insert` perhaps) instead of `xdmp:node-insert`.

This bug was fixed in 8.0-3, so upgrading to latest should get you round this. See also: http://markmail.org/message/z6bpgskahs3zkw6v

HTH!